# How to handle strong ceiling effects in an repeated measurment experiment?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, inference, nonparametric, experiment-design

i am trying to analyse some old data.
It's an between-within subject experiment with 4 experimental conditions and 2 points of measurment.
The question is, if there are differences in effect of the experimental conditions/interventions.

Unluckily there are extraordinary strong ceiling effects at the pre-test/measurment point 1.
Around 50% of the participants already reach the maximum performance - so they cannot realy improve.

My solution is the following:

- I create a variable Post-Pre measuring the intervention effect.
- Then i get rid of all participants with no change value = 0
- I create a new ordinal variable with the rest of the data indicating positive or negative change

Now i plot a contigency table with my new ordinal variable and the nominal experimental conditions.
I calculate a Chi² Test to test for global effects. Then i use Pearson Residuals to interprete the results & Cramers V for a global strength of effect.

Is this a good approach to deal with the situation? Could you think of other approaches?

Edit: The response measures the amount of correct answers. It is a metric variable but not continous. My sample size is ~250 persons. It's a psychological intervention to improve the quality of writing of students.

Comment: What does your variables measure? Is the response continuous/ordinal/... ? sample size? nature of intervention? what kind /how many predictors ? ... We need some more information!!!

Comment: The response measures the amount of correct answers. It is a metric variable but not continous. My sample size is  ~250 persons. It's a psychological intervention to improve the quality of writing of students.

Comment: Please add this new information as an edit to the question. Not everybody reads comments!